# Non-greedy operator on re.sub

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string:

```
>>> s = 'Claude Binyon [Director / Screenwriter] Walter Benjamin Hare [Play Author]'
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
'Claude Binyon,Walter Benjamin Hare,'
```

I have the following regex, but it is greedy, so is replacing everything after the `[`. How would I make the following non-greedy to work as needed?

```
>>> re.sub('\[.+]',',',s)
'Claude Binyon ,'
```

Comment: replace `.+` with `.+?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
>>> re.sub('\[.+?]',',',s)
```